# How is Google getting Descriptions for Wikipedia pages if they don't have a meta-description?

Tags: java, html, wikipedia

I was wanting to write a bot that uses Wikipedia meta descriptions to answer questions input by the user, but they don't use meta descriptions, yet, google results seem to have perfectly cut out descriptions for the pages, so.. I want to get that.

I am using Jsoup to get my descriptions and everything is great if the webpage has a meta description, so I don't feel like I need to show code but you want it some reason I can.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia leaves the meta descriptions blank, as you said. Have a look at [this article](https://ahrefs.com/blog/technical-seo/). It has a section on meta descriptions. Effectively, Google just pulls out the first sentence or two from the article.